# Why does the derivative of Dirichlet integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{ax}}{x} dx$ with respect to $a$ gives nonsense?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, conditional-convergence

If I define $I(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{ax}}{x} dx$. We know that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{ax}}{x} dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$. If I differentiate both sides by $a$ then we get $\int_0^\infty \cos{ax} dx=0$. Clearly LHS is undefined, what's going on here?

Comment: who tells you that $\frac{d\int f(x,y)dx}{dy}=\int \frac{df(x,y)}{dy}dx$ ??? It is absolutely true that the derivative of the integral is zero, but it is absolutely false that said derivative is the integral of the derivative of the original integrand

Comment: Actually $I(a)$ is not $\frac{\pi}{2}$ but $\frac{\pi}{2}\text{sign}(a)$, which is not differentiable at the origin. And you are not always allowed to differentiate under the integral sign.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I know and therefore I'm not differentiating at 0. Say a=47 and we've still got problem at our hands

Answer (score 1):

Let $$F(a)=\int_0^b\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}dx.$$ Let $t=ax$. Then $$F(a)=\int_0^{ab}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt.$$Thus
$$F(a)=\operatorname{Si}(ab)\implies F'(a)=\frac{\sin(ab)}{ab}b=\frac{\sin(ab)}{a}.$$ The $b\to\infty$ limit of $\sin(ab)$ does not exist.

Comment: Agreed but then why the RHS looks differentiable. RHS is a constant function which should be differentiable right?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(a,x)=\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}$. What you did was interchange integral and derivative:
$$\frac d{da}\mathcal I_x f = \mathcal I_x\partial_a f,$$ where $\mathcal I_x$ is shorthand for $\int_0^\infty\cdot\,dx.$ [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) is the relevant theorem here. The bounds are not finite, though, so one should look at [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement). For the interchange to work, one needs integrable function $g\colon [0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ such that for all $a$ and almost every $x$ we have $|\cos(ax)|\leq g(x).$ There is no such $g$ since $t\mapsto \int_0^t|\cos(ax)|\,dx$ grows without bound. So, the interchange is not justified.

That doesn't mean that one still couldn't do it. However, you explicitly showed that you can't and that is in no way problematic, since no theorem says that it can always be done.

EDIT: By the comment of Jack D'Aurizio, $\mathcal I_xf$ is not differentiable at $0$, so even if the bounds were finite, one can't interchange integration and differentiation since the assumptions of the Leibniz integral rule are not satisfied.